# Read in big csv file, validate and write out using uniVocity parser

Tags: validation, parsing, csv

I need to parse a big csv file (2gb). The values have to be validated, the rows containing "bad" fields must be dropped and a new file containing only valid rows ought to be output.

I've selected uniVocity parser library to do that. Please help me to understand whether this library is well-suited for the task and what approach should be used.

1. Given the file size, what is the best way to organize read->validate->write in uniVocity ? Read in all rows at once or use iterator style ? Where parsed and validated rows should be stored before they are written to file ?
2. Is there a way in Univocity to access row's values by index ? Something like row.getValue(3) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of this library, let me try to help you out:

1. First, do not try to read all rows at once as you will fill your memory with LOTS of data.
2. You can get the row values by index.

The faster approach to read/validate/write would be by using a `RowProcessor` that has a `CsvWriter` and decides when to write or skip a row. I think the following code will help you a bit:

#### Define the output:

```
private CsvWriter createCsvWriter(File output, String encoding){
    CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings();
    //configure the writer ...

    try {
        return new CsvWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output), encoding), settings);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error writing to " + output.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    }
}
```

#### Redirect the input

```
//this creates a row processor for our parser. It validates each row and sends them to the csv writer.
private RowProcessor createRowProcessor(File output, String encoding){
    final CsvWriter writer = createCsvWriter(output, encoding);
    return new AbstractRowProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            if (shouldWriteRow(row)) {
                writer.writeRow(row);
            } else {
                //skip row
            }
        }

        private boolean shouldWriteRow(String[] row) {
            //your validation here
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void processEnded(ParsingContext context) {
            writer.close();
        }
    };
}
```

#### Configure the parser:

```
public void readAndWrite(File input, File output, String encoding) {

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    //configure the parser here

    //tells the parser to send each row to them custom processor, which will validate and redirect all rows to the CsvWriter
    settings.setRowProcessor(createRowProcessor(output, encoding));

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    try {
        parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input), encoding));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to open input file " + input.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    }
}
```

For better performance you can also wrap the row processor in a `ConcurrentRowProcessor`.

```
settings.setRowProcessor(new ConcurrentRowProcessor(createRowProcessor(output, encoding)));
```

With this, the writing of rows will be performed in a separate thread.

Comment: thanks man. that helped a lot. one last thing, how would I go about geting row values by the index from the inside of the custom row processor ?

Comment: What about this: 

`private boolean shouldWriteRow(String[] row) {
      String valueAtIndex10 = row[10];
      return true; 
}`